# How to get around the Linux "Too Many Arguments" limit

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-sqs

I have to pass 256Kb of text as an argument to the "aws sqs" command but am running into a limit in the command-line at around 140Kb. This has been discussed in many places that [it been solved in the Linux kernel as of  2.6.23 kernel](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_23#line-84).

But cannot get it to work. I am using `3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64`

Here's a simple example to test:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

SIZE=1000
while [ $SIZE -lt 300000 ]
do
   echo "$SIZE"
   VAR="`head -c $SIZE < /dev/zero | tr '\0' 'a'`"
   ./foo "$VAR"
   let SIZE="( $SIZE * 20 ) / 19"
done
```

And the `foo` script is just:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "$1" | wc -c
```

And the output for me is:

```
117037
123196
123196
129680
129680
136505
./testCL: line 11: ./foo: Argument list too long
143689
./testCL: line 11: ./foo: Argument list too long
151251
./testCL: line 11: ./foo: Argument list too long
159211
```

So, the question how do I modify the `testCL` script is it can pass 256Kb of data? Btw, I have tried adding `ulimit -s 65536` to the script and it didn't help.

And if this is plain impossible I can deal with that but can you shed light on this quote from my link above

> "While Linux is not Plan 9, in 2.6.23 Linux is adding variable
>   argument length. Theoretically you shouldn't hit frequently "argument
>   list too long" errors again, but this patch also limits the maximum
>   argument length to 25% of the maximum stack limit (ulimit -s)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

***edit:***

**I was finally able to pass <= 256 KB as a single command line argument (see *edit (4)* in the bottom). However, please read carefully how I did it and decide for yourself if this is a way you want to go. At least you should be able to understand why you are 'stuck' otherwise from what I found out.**

---

With the coupling of `ARG_MAX` to `ulim -s` / 4 came the introduction of `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` as max. length of an argument:

```c
/*
 *  linux/fs/exec.c
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 1991, 1992  Linus Torvalds
 */
```

> ...

```c
#ifdef CONFIG_MMU
/*
 * The nascent bprm->mm is not visible until exec_mmap() but it can
 * use a lot of memory, account these pages in current->mm temporary
 * for oom_badness()->get_mm_rss(). Once exec succeeds or fails, we
 * change the counter back via acct_arg_size(0).
 */
```

> ...

```c
static bool valid_arg_len(struct linux_binprm *bprm, long len)
{
 return len <= MAX_ARG_STRLEN;
}
```

> ...

```c
#else
```

> ...

```c
static bool valid_arg_len(struct linux_binprm *bprm, long len)
{
  return len <= bprm->p;
}

#endif /* CONFIG_MMU */
```

> ...

```c
static int copy_strings(int argc, struct user_arg_ptr argv,
      struct linux_binprm *bprm)
{
```

> ...

```c
    str = get_user_arg_ptr(argv, argc);
```

> ...

```c
    len = strnlen_user(str, MAX_ARG_STRLEN);
    if (!len)
      goto out;

    ret = -E2BIG;
    if (!valid_arg_len(bprm, len))
      goto out;
```

> ...

```c
}
```

> ...

`MAX_ARG_STRLEN` is defined as 32 times the page size in `linux/include/uapi/linux/binfmts.h`:

> ...

```c
/*
 * These are the maximum length and maximum number of strings passed to the
 * execve() system call.  MAX_ARG_STRLEN is essentially random but serves to
 * prevent the kernel from being unduly impacted by misaddressed pointers.
 * MAX_ARG_STRINGS is chosen to fit in a signed 32-bit integer.
 */
#define MAX_ARG_STRLEN (PAGE_SIZE * 32)
#define MAX_ARG_STRINGS 0x7FFFFFFF
```

> ...

The default page size is 4 KB so you cannot pass arguments longer than 128 KB.

I can't try it now but maybe switching to huge page mode (page size 4 MB) if possible on your system solves this problem.

For more detailed information and references see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842/65290) to [a similar question on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120642/65290).

---

***edits:***

***(1)***
According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80767/65290) one can change the page size of `x86_64` Linux to 1 MB by enabling `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE` and setting `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE_MADVISE` to `n` in the kernel config.

***(2)***
After recompiling my kernel with the above configuration changes `getconf PAGESIZE` still returns 4096.
According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128407/65290) `CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE` is also needed which I could pull in via `CONFIG_HUGETLBFS`. I am recompiling now and will test again.

***(3)***
I recompiled my kernel with `CONFIG_HUGETLBFS` enabled and now `/proc/meminfo` contains the corresponding `HugePages_*` entries mentioned in [the corresponding section of the kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt).
However, the page size according to `getconf PAGESIZE` is still unchanged. So while I should be able now to request huge pages via `mmap` calls, the kernel's default page size determining `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` is still fixed at 4 KB.

***(4)***
I modified `linux/include/uapi/linux/binfmts.h` to `#define MAX_ARG_STRLEN (PAGE_SIZE * 64)`, recompiled my kernel and now your code produces:

> ...

```
117037
123196
123196
129680
129680
136505
143689
151251
159211
```

> ...

```
227982
227982
239981
239981
252611
252611
265906
./testCL: line 11: ./foo: Argument list too long
279901
./testCL: line 11: ./foo: Argument list too long
294632
./testCL: line 11: ./foo: Argument list too long
```

So now the limit moved from 128 KB to 256 KB as expected.
I don't know about potential side effects though.
As far as I can tell, my system seems to run just fine.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was asking for. In my case it sort of means it's impossible (ie. cannot run custom kernels) But its very useful the know I am stuck and to know **why**. Btw, the error message "Argument list too long" is misleading especially since that part is actually fixed. Its the size of an individual argument was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the arguments into some file, and modify your program to accept "arguments" from a file. A common convention (notably used by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and several other GNU programs) is that an argument like `@/tmp/arglist.txt` asks your program to read arguments from file `/tmp/arglist.txt`, often one line per argument

You might perhaps pass some data thru long environment variables, but they also are limited (and what is limited *by the kernel* in fact is the size of `main`'s initial stack, containing both program arguments and the environment)

Alternatively, modify your program to be configurable thru some configuration file which would contain the information you want to pass thru arguments.

<sup>(If you can recompile your kernel, you might try to increase -to a bigger power of two much smaller than your available RAM, e.g. to 2097152- the `ARG_MAX` which is `#define`-d in `linux-4.*/include/uapi/linux/limits.h` before recompiling your kernel)</sup>

In other ways, there is no way to circumvent that limitation (see [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) man page and its *Limits on size of arguments and environment* section) - once you have raised your stack limit (using [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_STACK`, generally with `ulimit` builtin in the parent shell). You need to deal with it otherwise.

Comment: The `foo` program cannot be modified. I am really calling the AWS SQS command-line tool and the message has to be passed as a value.

Comment: @swdev: You need to specify the constraints in your question. Another approach would be to pass arguments to sqs using `xargs`.

Comment: @tuxdna, the problem is a single argument (the sqs message) is huge. I don't think `xargs` will help since I cannot split the message. Yeah, I tried to simplify my question about SQS CLI just with a way to duplicate the args too big issue. That probably backfired on me. Answers that are just redesign the call are not really useful to me. Actually answers that prove it is just impossible are useful then I redesign my program with a smaller message. For example, what am I misunderstanding about the quote above. It says it possible so why is it impossible (ie. "you are struck")

Comment: Perhaps you are sending a message using sqs, where the message is provided as a CLI argument. However, i think there would be other ways of sending the message - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/send-message.html

Comment: Even if you manage to increase CLI argument size limit, there will always be a constraint on a system resources. So it is better to find alternative ways, to accomplish your task.

Comment: Maybe you can try the `aws sqs send-message-batch` command, which is like `send-message` but takes its inputs, including the message body, from a file.

Comment: @mark, thanks. I am using your work around. Can even use bash process substitution to avoid creating a real file. `aws sqs send-message-batch --queue-url $QUEUE_URL --entries file://<(makeGiantMsg)`